# vb.net - check if there are duplicate data in Datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

How do I check if there are duplicate in datagridview?

I have this code:

```
For x As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    For y As Integer = x + 1 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        If DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value.ToString = DataGridView1.Rows(y).Cells(0).Value.ToString Then
            MsgBox("Duplicate Data!")
            Exit Sub
        Else
            save_data()
            Me.Close()
        End If
    Next
Next
```

the code above is okay if the duplicate data is following each other like this:

```
Column1 (cell 0)  |  Column2 (cell 1)
------------------|------------------
TEST              |  NAME
TEST              |  NAME2
```

and the "Duplicate Data!" Message Box appears.

But when the duplicate data is not following each other it will go to the `else` statement where it will be saved. Like this:

```
Column1 (cell 0)  |  Column2 (cell 1)
------------------|------------------
TEST              |  NAME
TEST2             |  NAME3
TEST              |  NAME2
```

and the data will be saved. as shown in the `else` statement.

What should I do so that even if the duplicate data are not following each other the `MsgBox("Duplicate Data!")` still appears?

Comment: So get rid of the `Else`. What point does it actually serve? Obviously you don't want to stop comparing if the first comparison doesn't yield a duplicate so don't write code that does that.  It should be obvious that you only want to save the data if you get through the entire loop without finding a match so it should be obvious that your code to save needs to be after the loop. This is what happens when you try to write code without understanding what it actually has to do, i.e. not the end result but rather the steps to get to that result.

Comment: Also, you might want to check your loop limits. How can you check the last row to the row after it?

Comment: I want to save it if there are no duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second For Loop you should check ALL rows other than the index you're on with the first loop, instead of index + 1. Also as mentioned, clean up that else statement because it will prevent the whole grid from being checked.  Call your Save_Data at the end of looping if no duplicates were found.  Use a Boolean to keep track.

```
Dim bolDuplicateWasFound As Boolean = False

For x As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    For y As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        If y <> x AndAlso DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value.ToString = DataGridView1.Rows(y).Cells(0).Value.ToString Then
            bolDuplicateWasFound = True
            MsgBox("Duplicate Data!")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
Next

If Not bolDuplicateWasFound Then
    Save_Data()
End If
```