# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Duplicate field''

Tags: mysql, vb.net

When I try to insert data into database,it shows as

> ' MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException:Duplicate field '

even though it is not a primary key.  Also I use a  code to check for duplicates in my datagridview.

```vb
If DataGridView1.RowCount = 0 Then
    Dim x As DialogResult
    x = MessageBox.Show("Enter the Values", "TDP Thermoline",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
Else
    Dim bolDuplicateWasFound As Boolean = False
    For x As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        For y As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            If y <> x AndAlso DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells("Date").Value = DataGridView1.Rows(y).Cells("Date").Value.ToString Then
                MessageBox.Show("Duplicate Found" & DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells("Date").Value.ToString)
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
    Next
    If Not bolDuplicateWasFound Then
        Dim command As MySqlCommand
        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1 Step +1
            command = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO `daily_production`(`Year`, `Month`, `Date`, `White`, `Yellow`) 
            VALUES (@yea,@mon,@dat,@whit,@yel)", db.getConnection)
            command.Parameters.Add("@yea", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString
            command.Parameters.Add("@mon", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString
            command.Parameters.Add("@dat", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value.ToString
            command.Parameters.Add("@whit", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value.ToString
            command.Parameters.Add("@yel", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value.ToString
            db.getConnection.Open()
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
        MessageBox.Show("Data Insert", "TDP Thermoline", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        db.getConnection.Close()
        db.getConnection.Dispose()
    End If
End If
```

How can I remove that error?

Comment: Could you please enter the complete ddl for the daily_production table into your question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50264301/vb-net-check-if-there-are-duplicate-data-in-datagridview did you just copy paste that answer? TBH that answer is even wrong because if a duplicate is *found* it will exit the sub anyways and `If Not bolDuplicateWasFound Then` will never be reached. Also turn `Option Strict On`, `DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells("Date").Value = DataGridView1.Rows(y).Cells("Date").Value.ToString` is an issue because you are trying to compare `Object` to `String`.

Comment: Finally add `.ToString()` to `DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells("Date").Value` to look like `DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells("Date").Value.ToString()`. Look into `Using` statements as well to `Dispose` of your objects when you are done with them; for ex: `Using command As New MySqlCommand()`...

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: Can we see how you filled the grid in the first place.